# How can I make these JS code more elegant?

Tags: javascript, typescript, coding-style, es6-promise

I have encounter a coding problem. I try to insert some style elements to HTML, and when these style loaded, console log "done"

```js
var genStyle = () => {
  const instance = {}
  setTimeout(() => {
    instance.onload && instance.onload()
  }, Math.random() * 3000)
  return instance
}

var a = genStyle()
var b = genStyle()
var c = genStyle()

/* implementation start */

Promise.all([

]).then(() => console.log('all done'))

/* implementation end */
```

I complete it like this, but I think its ugly. Could you give a more elegant one?

```js
var genStyle = () => {
  const instance = {}
  setTimeout(() => {
    instance.onload && instance.onload()
  }, Math.random() * 3000)
  return instance
}

var a = genStyle()
var b = genStyle()
var c = genStyle()

/* implementation start */

const wrapper = x => {
  let tick = null
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => tick = resolve)
  x.onload = tick
  return promise
}

Promise.all([
  wrapper(a),
  wrapper(b),
  wrapper(c)
]).then(() => console.log('all done'))

/* implementation end */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for there to be an outer `tick` variable that gets reassigned to the resolve function - you can return the Promise directly.

```
const wrapper = x => new Promise((resolve) => {
  x.onload = resolve;
});
```

Ideally you'd also have an array of instances instead of 3 separate standalone identifiers to begin with, if that's something you're permitted to do.

```js
const genStyle = () => {
  const instance = {}
  setTimeout(() => {
    instance.onload && instance.onload()
  }, Math.random() * 3000)
  return instance
}

const instances = [genStyle(), genStyle(), genStyle()];
const wrapper = x => new Promise((resolve) => {
  x.onload = resolve;
});

Promise.all(
  instances.map(wrapper)
)
  .then(() => console.log('all done'))
```